# SevenZipSharp Password Check?

Tags: sevenzipsharp

In the past i was suggested to use SevenZipExtractor.Check() to see if a file is password protected. This solution is giving me problems as Check() does an integrity check which means it decompresses everything. This takes far to long with the amount, size and compression level of the files i am running it on.

How do i check if a archive has a password? It would also be useful if there is a way i can check if what i think is the password is correct without extracting all the files.

Comment: @Oded: ... the solution should work for ALL filetypes it supports. Specifically .7z files are giving me the problem. One of my previous SO question (or maybe i found it on sevenzipsharp forums) suggested it. I tried looking at their site, documentation (non exist) and than i used the source code and pause the debugger to find the exact line/problem and its Check extracting full file instead of what i thought it was doing. Checking if the password is correct. There was no doc so there was no way for me to know w/o looking at source code